# Does Google App Engine's git Push-to-Deploy also update backends?

Tags: git, google-app-engine, python-2.7

When using `appcfg.py`, I had to specify `backends` to update them.

What about when I'm using Push-to-Deploy?

I ask because I see two of my Versions don't have the same "deployed" date -- the backend still says "6 days ago". I didn't change `backends.yaml`, but I did change the code that runs on that backend.

Should I see a new "deployed" date? Is git Push-to-Deploy working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No -- It doesn't update backends.

(My cron jobs ran last night and failed because they were running old code.)

Nothin' like good ol' `appcfg.py update ./ --backends`